# Facebook comments not sorting correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I use the comments moderation tool from Facebook embedded onto my website so I can interact with participants doing my 30 Day Challenge.

However for some reason, the embedded comments on one page automatically defaults to sorting by Oldest first, even though I have in my settings selected Newest. All my other pages seem to be okay for now.

Any idea as to what could be causing this just to happen on one page? And how to fix it?

Thanks! Kym.

Comment: What does your code to embed the plugin look like on that specific page? Any chance the `order_by`/ `data-order-by` parameter gets set explicitly there ...?

Comment: Unfortunately not @CBroe, but thanks for pointing that out! It seems I have fixed the issue now by putting that `data-order-by="reverse_time"` parameter into the code on the page :) Not sure what changed within the plugin so it didn't automatically sort them the way it's supposed to, but thanks again for pointing that out, I didn't even think to add anything like that